# What HTTP code should an API return when the body of a POST/PUT request should not be empty?

Tags: rest, http

I would naturally go for the code `400 Bad Request` but I would like to have your opinions on that.

Comment: You could use `422 Unprocessable Entity`, But as far as I know I would still prefer `400` to notify this kind of issue

Comment: Thanks @OlivierDepriester. Can you elaborate on why would you prefer a `400` over a `422`?

Comment: `422` is to be used when the request body syntax is correct but the values of the related entity prevent it from being processed (example; the entity owns a month attribute whose value is greater than 12). In your case, you don't even have an entity to process. Thus, I would consider it as a malformed request.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918.html#section-11.2) describes a useful heuristic.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

A request with `Content-Type: application/json` would return 400 (because the [JSON grammar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2) requires a value).

But for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoding`, an empty document is well formed (that's how you describe an [empty list of name-value tuples](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded)).  If an empty list of name-value tuples doesn't make sense (aka: *semantically* erroneous), then we return a 422.